# htaccess 301 redirect not working for new subdomain site

Tags: .htaccess

I'm moving my site so wanted to test a page and redirect in the htaccess file:

I wanted to redirect

> http://www.martinspencephotography.co.uk/blog/yes/mini-photo-series-minimalism-gallows-hill-outside-cloughmills

to

> http://landscape.martinspencephotography.co.uk/minimalism-at-gallows-hill/

using the following in the .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/yes/mini-photo-series-minimalism-gallows-hill-outside-cloughmill http://landscape.martinspencephotography.co.uk/minimalism-at-gallows-hill
```

It didn't works there any reason why this might not work?

Comment: Look closer at the end of rule, and letter "S"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule your_page.html
http://your.url.fr/yournewpage.html [R=301]
```

And what about

```
http://www.martinspencephotography.co.uk/blog/yes/mini-photo-series-minimalism-gallows-hill-outside-cloughmills http://landscape.martinspencephotography.co.uk/minimalism-at-gallows-hill/ [R=301]
```

So the answer was to use DRUPAL NODE...

Comment: Thanks Joel I tried that but it didn't work either. One site is in Drupal and the other is in WordPress so the .html doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I found I needed to use DRUPAL NODE to do the redirect